# systemd drop-in unit, ExecStartPre as root user, ExecStart as custom user

Tags: server, systemd, services

I have a web service running using systemd, this service runs by its own user, and I would like to execute some ExecStartPre commands but running as root user. So more in detail:

*i.e /lib/systemd/system/webservice.service*

```
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/web
Group=webuser
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/usr/share/web
RuntimeDirectory=web
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0750
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/web --config=/etc/web/config.ini                               

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and I would like to have a drop-in service where it fetches from a web-source the config.ini file

*i.e  /etc/systemd/system/web.service.d/local.conf*

```
[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly=true
RestartSec=5
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
ExecStartPre=+/usr/bin/curl http://some.url --output /etc/web/config.ini 
ExecStartPre=+chown web:web /etc/web/config.ini
```

The configuration above is not working since my service is freezing during the startup without any message in any log. Is there any way I can make something like that to work?

Comment: Is the configuration you posted doing what you want? I can't tell if you need help getting this to work if you want to know if there is a cleaner way.

Comment: You are right, I reformulate my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your systemd setup is correct.  If the terminal hangs when you start the service then I would suspect the `ExecStartPre` command is not exiting.

I ran the following commands as root on an Ubuntu 20.04 server to test a similar service setup.

Create a user for the service.

```
useradd --system myservice
```

Create a script for the service that logs the user the script is running as and loops.

```
cat <<'EOF' > /usr/local/bin/myservice.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# first argument is loop count, defaults to infinite
i=${1:--1}
while :; do
  date >> ${RUNTIME_DIRECTORY:-/tmp}/run.log
  whoami >> ${RUNTIME_DIRECTORY:-/tmp}/run.log
  (( --i == 0 )) && break
  sleep ${SLEEP:-60}
done
EOF
```

Add the service file and the override file.

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service
[Unit]
Description=My Service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/myservice
Type=simple
User=myservice
Group=myservice
Restart=on-failure
RuntimeDirectory=myservice
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0750
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/myservice.sh
EOF

mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.d/
cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/myservice.sh 1
ExecStartPre=chown myservice.myservice /run/myservice/run.log
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload
```

Start the service

```
systemctl start myservice.service
```

The result is as expected.  The `run.log` file shows the script ran once as `root` and then continues running as the `myservice` user until the service is stopped.

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls -al /run/myservice/
total 4
drwxr-x---  2 myservice myservice   60 Feb 27 18:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 30 root      root      1080 Feb 27 18:23 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 myservice myservice   73 Feb 27 18:23 run.log
root@ubuntu:~# cat /run/myservice/run.log
Sun Feb 27 18:23:14 UTC 2022
root
Sun Feb 27 18:23:14 UTC 2022
myservice
Sun Feb 27 18:24:14 UTC 2022
myservice
```

I did find that if the `ExecStartPre` command enters the loop then the terminal appears to hang when the service is started.  That could explain why you think your service is freezing.  The `ExecStartPre` command may still be running or may be unable to complete.

**Other Notes**

- I found that using either `PermissionsStartOnly=true` or `ExecStartPre=+...` had the same effect of running the `ExecStartPre` script as root.